# How does the Casorati-Weierstrass Theorem not contradict Picard's Theorem?

Tags: complex-analysis

I was looking at a proof regarding the Casorati-Weierstrass Theorem [here](https://planetmath.org/proofofcasoratiweierstrasstheorem) and it got me thinking, using this set up can't one get a contradiction with Picard's Theorem?

For example, if we let  $f(z)=e^\frac{1}{z}$ in the above proof and we consider $\lambda = 0$ don't we get that there must be some $z_0$ such that $f(z_0)=0$ which would be a contradiction as it is often given that an example case of Picard's Theorem is that $0$ does not appear for $f(z)$?

Thank you in advance for the help. If the question is clear to understand please let me know.

Comment: No, where do you get that $z_0$? All it says is that $f$ attains values arbitrarily close to $\lambda=0$.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the comment. I have a question about the proof then. Isn't the contradiction set up in the way that we show that $f$ must attain that value? What I am trying to say is I am not sure how the given proof shows it gets arbitrarily close rather than actually attaining that value.

Comment: No, the assumption is “there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that $|f(z)-\lambda|>\epsilon$”. That's not the same as assuming $f(z) \neq \lambda$.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Is it the case that this is not the same as one deals with an open set of points whilst the other with omitting a single one? If not could you please clarify the difference?

Comment: Yes, disallowing a whole disk of values is not the same thing as disallowing the single value $\lambda$. If you only assumed that $\lambda$ is not attained, then you wouldn't be able to say that $1/(f(z)-\lambda)$ is bounded.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. It is all perfectly clear to me now. If you would like, you can post this as an answer below so that I can mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assumption which leads to a contradition is that there is a whole disk of values around $\lambda$ which are not attained, and the conclusion is then that $f$ must assume values arbitrarily close to $\lambda$.

If the assumption were that the single value $\lambda$ is not attained, then a contradiction would indeed imply that $\lambda$ is attained. However, it's impossible to derive such a contradiction (as shown by your counterexample), and the place where the current argument would break down is when it's claimed that $1/(f(z)-\lambda)$ is bounded.